# Ignore empty tags in xmlunit

Tags: java, xmlunit

Is there any way to completely ignore an empty tag in XMLUnit so that it is not taken into account for comparison?
Ex:

```
<a>
<b/>
<c>data1</c>
<d>data2</d>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
<c>data1</c>
<d>data2</d>
</a>
```

should not return any difference. 
Is there any inbuilt function for doing this? 
Thank you.

Comment: i think empty tags (no attribute or content) should be ignored entirely, unless their presence is explicitly mandatory via schema

Comment: @NitinSingh It gives the difference as: Expected element tag name 'b' but was 'c' and then compares the c tag with the d tag.

Comment: You can use a `NodeFilter` in order to suppress all empty elements. In general an empty element is certainly not the same as no element at all, think of the effect of an empty `hr` tag on an HTML page, for example.

Comment: @StefanBodewig thank you. But I am new to XMLunit and unable to find documentation for NodeFilter and am not able to implement it. Could you help with the same? Thank you.

Comment: I created an answer as the response would have become too long for a comment. :-)

Answer (score 5):

In general an empty tag is not the same as a missing tag, that's why XMLUnit complains. In XMLUnit 2.x you can suppress the comparison of nodes with a `NodeFilter`. `NodeFilter` is a predicate function that accepts a single DOM `Node` and returns `true` if the node should be considered while comparing documents. The default-implementation simply returns `true` for all `Node`s that are not the document type declaration.

You could use something like the following (untested) class

```
class SuppressEmptyElements implements Predicate<Node> {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Node n) {
        if (n instanceof Element) {
            return !isEmpty((Element) n);
        }
        // not an element - a commment, nested text and so on
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(Element e) {
        return e.getAttributes().getLength() == 0 && e.getChildNodes().getLength() == 0;
    }
}
```

When using `DiffBuilder` you'd use something like `withNodeFilter(new SuppressEmptyElements())`. The longer story can be found in XMLUnit's [user guide](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#nodefilter-and-attributefilter).

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. But I am getting a runtime error now. I am not sure if this has to do with XMLUnit but it would be great if you could take a look!  `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.io.BufferedReader does not have a no-arg default constructor.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at java.io.BufferedReader `

Comment: Since the entire error could not be posted in one comment, I'll post it again: `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.io.BufferedReader does not have a no-arg default constructor.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at java.io.BufferedReader

 at org.xmlunit.builder.JaxbBuilder.build(JaxbBuilder.java:93)
 at org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder.getSource(DiffBuilder.java:134)
 at org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder.compare(DiffBuilder.java:119)`

Comment: It is probably easier if you open a bug report over at https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/ and try to add a small testcase reproducing the problem.

Comment: This solution did not work for me, because it filter out cases where the control XML has an empty node (so it gets filtered), but the test XML has the same node not empty

Comment: Works like a charm. Used w/o changes. Thanks!